# Get bluetooth previously paired list from settings

Tags: ios, bluetooth

On the iPhone settings -> bluetooth - under "MY DEVICES" header you can see a list of previously paired bluetooth devices.

How can i get this list on my app? this are not only BLE devices so i don't think i can see them via coreBluetooth.

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You can't as far as I know. I think Apple believes that it would be a security issue if any app could know information about all the peripherals that you use.